# Help in placing "2 parboxes in a single Row" in Bulleted or numbered Items

Tags: itemize, parbox

I want to make a book which has many instructions for solving mathematical problems and equations. It describes each step for equation solving. There are many steps.
Each step is different item.  The page is divided into two part. There is a paragraph with description in left and in the right "there are equations in intermediate states"

So, overall page layout looks like this.

Step 1.
Lorem ipsum dolor int.........        < equations >

Step 2.
Lorem ipsum dolor int..........        < equations >

Step 3.
Lorem ipsum dolor int..........        < equations >

Step 4.
Lorem ipsum dolor int..........        < equations >

I am new to latex. I know concepts of minipages, Parbox, item and tables.

But I am not able to figure out that. I tried to search but didn't found what I was looking.
Please guide me how to make it work.

EDIT: Edited for minor grammatical errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `paracol` package might be a good option for you.

I made a simple list that looks like your layout using `enumitem`. You need to remove the skips above and below the list to get equations to line up easily, but you can fiddle around with things depending on your exact set up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{step}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[step]{
  label=Step \arabic*., resume, leftmargin=5em, topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt,
  after=\vspace{2ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}
}

\columnratio{0.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{step}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{step}

\switchcolumn

\noindent
\begin{equation}
  x = y
\end{equation}

\switchcolumn*

\begin{step}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{step}

\switchcolumn

\noindent
\begin{equation}
  x = y
\end{equation}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]