# How to make a new "List of Instructions" similar to "list of tables", "List of Image"

Tags: table-of-contents

I am making a math book, which has many step by step instructions to solve problems. I want to make a list of All Instructions in beginning which similar to the table of contents "List of Images" and "List of Tables" we have.

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: You need a MWE :-). But in any case you probably look for for the package `tocloft` in combination with `listing`. Have look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306858/list-of-listings-similar-to-list-of-figures

Comment: Another possibility: [Table of equations like list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% newlistofprob.tex  (revised) SE 566579

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%% the next creates a \listofinstruction macro
\newlistof[chapter]{instruction}{ins}{All Instructions}
%%% a guess at your instruction command
%\newcommand{\instruction}[1]{%
%  \refstepcounter{instruction}
%  \par\noindent\textbf{Instruction \theinstruction} #1
%  \addcontentsline{ins}{instruction}{\protect\numberline{\theinstruction}}\par}
\newenvironment{instruction}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{instruction}
  \noindent
  \textbf{Instruction \theinstruction\ #1 }\par
  \addcontentsline{ins}{instruction}{\protect\numberline{\theinstruction}#1}%
  }%
  {\par}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
%% insert space in listofinstruction between chapters
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{ins}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\listofinstruction
\chapter{First}
\begin{instruction}{An instruction}
  text of the instruction
\end{instruction}

 %\instruction{Another instruction}
\begin{instruction}{Another instruction}
  text of the instruction
\end{instruction}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{instruction}{An instruction}
  text of the instruction
\end{instruction}

\begin{instruction}{Another instruction}
  text of the instruction
\end{instruction}

\end{document}
```

Please read the `tocloft` manual for more detailed explanation. As you have not provided an MWE I have no idea how you have coded for "instructions". I provided something but I'm sure that not what you have done, but it gives you an idea of what is needed to get an instruction into the `listofinstruction`.

**EDIT:** I have changed my answer to give what I think might be more appropriate for the OP.

Comment: Thank you, so much for the answer! My last question was about coding instructions are in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566312/help-in-placing-2-parboxes-in-a-single-row-in-bulleted-or-numbered-items). The answer for coding steps was just what I wanted and hence, is accepted. Instructions have a heading, then plain text as description and steps written using 'paracol' package.

Comment: Excuse my utterly noob question ,but I need to know what MWE stands for?

Comment: @Pratyush MWE --- Mininum Working Document --- code from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that we can compile that shows your problem. There is an emphasis on "Minimal" --- do not include lots of packages that are not relevant to the problem. You can use the `lipsum` package for including example text. And so on.